# Aggregating customer service emails from multiple ecommerce sites for easy handling

Tags: ecommerce, email, customer-service, aggregators

For one of my main customer help email addresses I use Mozilla Thunderbird with a combination of tags and saved searches.

As the number of my e-commerce sites grows from 1 to more, customer service handling gets more tricky.

Is there any simple and efficient way of handling emails from the different sites?

Perhaps what I'm looking for is a way of aggregating customer service emails from different sites, into one place?  Perhaps there's a way of already doing this within Thunderbird or Gmail?

Comment: Gmail and Thunderbird support the use of multiple POP3 or IMAP e-mail addresses and you can find out how to add multiple accounts by reading the documentation in either case. This question seems to fall outside the scope of the Pro Webmasters purpose, so I am voting to close as off-topic. FAQ: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: You may also consider a CRM like Zoho CRM or a dedicated support system like Zendesk.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by danlefree Thunderbird can handle multiple email accounts. They can go into their own separate folders or into one group of folders known as "local folders". Thunderbird also allows you to set up signatures and quickly switch identities when sending mail.

There are lots of tutorials on how to do this. [This one looks like a good one](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-mozilla-thunderbird-3-multiple-email/).

Answer (score 1):

I use an online help desk application for this. There is an open source program called osTicket, and the website is: http://osticket.com/

From their website:

osTicket is a widely-used open source support ticket system. It seamlessly integrates inquiries created via email, phone and web-based forms into a simple easy-to-use multi-user web interface. Manage, organize and archive all your support requests and responses in one place while providing your customers with accountability and responsiveness they deserve.

Basically what you would do would be to set up each of your sites as a department in osTickets. Each department can have its own e-mail address, e-mail templates/signatures, etc.

I have used this application on several sites and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Setup an account on http://www.desk.com and if you have one main company which manages all the ecommerce sites have a single email integrated with desk.com so all customers can be assigned a priority level and managed from a single interface

Comment: Isn't this the long way to solve a simple task?! Are you really using it? I can't even understand their "per hour" pricing policy. What's the catch?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio no it's not, for example WooThemes uses zendesk to manage all their customer support for all their products. I suggested desk.com since it's free to start with. If you don't understand their pricing policy and how a free account works you should email them.